# Computer spontaneously suspends & resets UEFI settings to default (motherboard power issue?)

Tags: bios, motherboard, hardware-failure, uefi, suspend

Apologies for the long question, but I have a strange collection of (hardware?) problems I can't fully figure out by myself.

**The device:**
My computer is an Acer Nitro 7 (Acer AN715-51-76ML) which came with Windows 10. I have also installed Ubuntu (first 20.04, now 21.10) as a dual-boot setup. I have made the following changes to the UEFI firmware settings:

- Enabled a BIOS password
- Disabled Secure Boot
- Reordered the boot menu to place Ubuntu first
- Changed SATA mode from 'RST Premium with Optane' to 'AHCI'
- Disabled the Keyboard Lighting Timeout

*(Note: I first made all these changes about 1 year and 8 months ago, long before the current spate of issues cropped up.)*

**The issue:**
After about 1 year and 8 months of use with no issues, strange 'episodes' started to occur sporadically:

1. Sometimes, the computer **will spontaneously enter suspend/sleep**. For a good 10 seconds or so after switching off, it becomes completely unresponsive, not even responding to the power button (held down, I think, long enough for what would normally cause it to start up or shut down). Then it spontaneously starts back up from suspend/sleep and I can resume my session as though nothing untoward has happened. *This has happened from Ubuntu 20.04, Ubuntu 21.10 & Windows 10, pre- & post-factory servicing, pre- & post-dusting (see below).*
2. Sometimes the above issue will escalate: the **spontaneous suspends follow each other in a burst**, several minutes apart. After having gone through the rigamarole about 5 times, give or take, **the UEFI firmware settings then spontaneously reset** to (what appear to be) the factory defaults - except for the BIOS password, which is retained. This causes some headaches with booting (because my Ubuntu install does not have drivers for the factory default SATA mode, RST Premium with Optane), but once I've got the settings set back to where I wanted them I can just boot as normal. *This has happened from Ubuntu 20.04 & Ubuntu 21.10, pre- & post-factory servicing, pre- & post-dusting (see below).*
3. Sometimes, **the computer will apparently lose contact with the SSD** containing the OS , resulting in a black screen with a barrage of error logs. I can hard quit with the power button & reboot normally, after which everything works fine again. *This has happened twice from Ubuntu 21.10, post-factory servicing, pre- & post-dusting (see below).*

*(Note: the events do not appear correlated to intensive processor or memory usage or anything like that - most happened while I was casually browsing the internet, perhaps watching a Youtube video. There **might** be a connection to times the computer was shaken or moved more than it normally is (e.g. taking it with me somewhere in my backpack, rather than letting it sit on the desk as usual), further reinforcing my suspicions of subtle hardware problems - but this may just be a coincidence.)*

**History:**

- Issue #1 first appeared in December, immediately escalating into issue #2. Both I & my local computer store's technical guy suspected hardware problems, so we had the computer shipped to Acer for repair.

  - Note: at this time, I did not yet understand the details of the problem. I was stuck with a computer that wouldn't boot in Ubuntu, and didn't yet realize that all I had to do to fix it was set the SATA mode back to 'AHCI'.
- We got it back from Acer with the comment that they had detected a 'BIOS issue' (perhaps because I had modified some firmware settings from their defaults?), and 'fixed' it by installing a fresh BIOS image. No mention was made of any hardware issues or hardware servicing.
- A few days after we got it back, issue #3 first occurred. Based on some cursory research I suspected that this might be caused by a separate hardware issue, possibly unrelated to the other problem, such as a loose connection between the motherboard and the SSD, or excessive dust buildup.
- I took the computer back into the shop, where it was opened, inspected, and thoroughly cleaned out *(Based on the comments I got about how full of dust the interior had been, I suspect it may not have been so much as opened when it was at Acer mere weeks earlier.)*
- Several hours after the computer was cleaned, issue #3 reoccurred. It has, however, not happened again in the weeks since then.
- A few weeks later, issue #1 reoccurred, and again escalated to issue #2. This time, I did some experimenting and was able to work out that all I needed to do to 'fix' it was quickly reset some UEFI firmware settings.
- In the weeks since then, issue #1 has reoccurred on two separate occasions, this time without escalating to issue #2.

Can anybody shed some light on what might possibly be the root cause of this (and, possibly, how it might be fixed)? I myself continue to suspect hardware problems along the lines of an interruption of power (or a spike of excess power?) to the motherboard, but honestly I don't know enough about hardware to speculate with any degree of confidence. In particular, I am skeptical of the idea that this is a pure BIOS problem that can be fixed with a simple reinstall: after all, when the problems first appeared, I had been using my computer without issue for 1 year and 8 months, and hadn't so much as opened the UEFI settings in a year, so I don't see what could have gone wrong at that moment.

The computer is still under warranty for another ~2 months, so I can still take advantage of Acer's services (or possibly even obtain a replacement if necessary), but since they weren't able to find the problem the first time, I want to further pin the cause down myself before sending the computer back in for another go.

Comment: Random firmware setting changes would make me suspicious of the CMOS battery, but I don't know how common they are on laptops any more.

Comment: Indeed apparently you can get replacement batteries for your model (https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/324816201959) and that would be my first look. https://www.google.com/search?q=AN715-51-76ML+cmos+battery

Comment: I've also had a "randomly disappearing SSD" before and it was a faulty drive. If it happens with any regularity I would replace it.

Comment: Best advice : Use the warranty to replace the computer. Don't try to fix it.